# My Sprites are not drawing even though there is no error?

Tags: c++, sfml

Here is my code.I just dont know why my sprites are not drawing. I used the window.draw() function in the nested for loop for 2d array of sprites but it is not drawing it.Just look at my nested loop for 2d array of sprites named `Board`. Help will be appreciated.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

using namespace sf;
int main()
{
    
    Music music;
    music.openFromFile("mainmusic.wav");
    music.play();

    
    
    


    

    bool drawRed = true;


    bool deletePlay = false;

    //Creating window for game
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "SFML", sf::Style::Close | Style::Titlebar);

    //creating rect of exact sem size as window to use it for a bg
    sf::RectangleShape player(sf::Vector2f(1280.0f, 720.0f));

    //creating a texture for starting background
    sf::Texture bg_texture;
    bg_texture.loadFromFile("candy_crushbg.jpg");
    player.setTexture(&bg_texture);

    //creating texture for play button
    Texture play;
    play.loadFromFile("cstartbtn.png");

    //creating sprite for play button texture 
    Sprite start;
    start.setTexture(play);
    start.setPosition(Vector2f(530, 490));
    start.setScale(Vector2f(0.2f, 0.2f));
    start.setOrigin(Vector2f(265, 245));
    
    //creating texture for playing background
    Texture startbg;
    startbg.loadFromFile("start_bg.jpg");
    


    int k, lower = 1, upper = 5, x = 400, y = 100;
    Texture RCandy, BCandy, OCandy, GCandy, YCandy;
    RCandy.loadFromFile("red_candy.png");
    BCandy.loadFromFile("blue_candy.png");
    OCandy.loadFromFile("orange_candy.png");
    GCandy.loadFromFile("green_candy.png");
    YCandy.loadFromFile("yellow_candy.png");
    Sprite Board[8][8];
    srand(time(0));
    int i, j, random;

    //loop for opening window
    while(window.isOpen()) {
        
        //creating event for game functions
        sf::Event evnt;
        Event play;


        //calling event in a loop
        while (window.pollEvent(evnt)) {

            switch (evnt.type) {
                //event for when we click close button
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
                //event when mouse is clicked on PLAY button
            case Event::MouseButtonPressed:
                //getting global boundaries of play button
                sf::Vector2f Mousepos = window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window));
                switch(evnt.key.code) {
                case Mouse :: Left:
                    //checking if mouse click is in the boundary of play button
                    if (start.getGlobalBounds().contains(Mousepos)) {
                        cout << "Sprite Clicked\n";
                        //deleting play button
                        deletePlay = true;
                        window.clear();
                        player.setTexture(&startbg);
                        `
                        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                            x = 400;
                            for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                                random = rand() % ((upper - lower) + lower) + 1;
                                cout << random << " ";
                                x = x + 50;
                                if (random == 1) {
                                    Board[i][j].setTexture(RCandy);
                                    Board[i][j].setPosition(x, y);
                                    Board[i][j].setScale(Vector2f(0.2f, 0.2f));
                                }
                                else if (random == 2) {
                                    Board[i][j].setTexture(OCandy);
                                    Board[i][j].setPosition(x, y);
                                    Board[i][j].setScale(Vector2f(0.2f, 0.2f));
                                }
                                else if (random == 3) {
                                    Board[i][j].setTexture(YCandy);
                                    Board[i][j].setPosition(x, y);
                                    Board[i][j].setScale(Vector2f(0.2f, 0.2f));
                                }
                                else if (random == 4) {
                                    Board[i][j].setTexture(GCandy);
                                    Board[i][j].setPosition(x, y);
                                    Board[i][j].setScale(Vector2f(0.2f, 0.2f));
                                }
                                else if (random == 5) {
                                    Board[i][j].setTexture(BCandy);
                                    Board[i][j].setPosition(x, y);
                                    Board[i][j].setScale(Vector2f(0.2f, 0.2f));
                                }
                                window.draw(Board[i][j]);
                                window.display();`
                            }
                            cout << endl;
                            y = y + 50;
                        }
                        
                            
                    }
                }
                break;


            }
        }
        

        
        window.draw(player);
        if (!deletePlay) {
            window.draw(start);
        }
        window.display();
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't check for errors that might tell you where the problem is.

Comment: @drescherjm No the files are in right folder. I think the problem is with the window.draw() function. It isn;t written at the right place.

Comment: @Galik There are no errors. :(

Comment: I believe he means you in the code you presented you are ignoring the return value for several of the sfml functions like `RCandy.loadFromFile("red_candy.png");` the `loadFromFile()` function returns a true / false value depending on if the load was successful or failed.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes! you are right, if there was an error loading these files this program wouldn't run but unfortunately everything works fine even the 2d array loop prints values how it should but only my sprites are not drawing.

Comment: You need to check the return values from functions like `RCandy.loadFromFile("red_candy.png");` to see if they have errors.

Comment: @Galik You see the sprites just flash on the screen for 1 sec or less and then disappear. And I don't know how to stop it from disappearing.

Comment: You create a sprite named player that is the size of the screen. You then draw stuff, then the "player" (which will draw OVER the stuff), then the play button, then display the window. Unless the "player" texture is transparent then this will be an issue. Also you have a switch statement comparing a keyboard key with a mouse button, those are different and should not be compared. You also shouldn't be calling display after drawing each item, as display swaps the buffers and then you have some items drawing in the back buffer, others drawing in the front buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must draw your board outside of the event loop.
Right now, your board is displayed only once (When you click on the left button of your mouse). You should write something like that after the 'window.clear();':

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
   for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
      window.draw(Board[i][j]);
```

Also, you must use 'window.display();' only once and at the end of the game loop.
If your want to draw the board as long as your the left button of your mouse is pressed, you can use:

```
if(sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
{
}
```